# Jquery rolloever - flickering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm working with some code that will have one highlighted state while the other elements are faded out. The problem I'm having with this build is that when you're moving across the elements fast, the effects tend to flicker. Is there something I'm missing or need to take out? Here's the code, then after the fiddle link

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.fn.wait = function(time, type) {
        time = time || 300;
        type = type || "fx";
        return this.queue(type, function() {
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(self).dequeue();
            }, time);
        });
    };
    $("#sites li:not(#sites li li)").hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('class', 'current'); // Add class .current
        $("#sites li:not(#sites li.current,#sites li li)").fadeTo("slow", 0.3); // Fade other items to 30%
        },function(){
        $("#sites li:not(#sites li.current,#sites li li)").wait().fadeTo(600, 1.0); // This should set the other's opacity back to 100% on mouseout
        $(this).removeClass("current"); // Remove class .current
    });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/racerxfactor/8msQ9/

Comment: Did you add the $.fn.wait to address the flickering issue? If you remove that, and then call .stop(), before fadeTo, that will address the flickering issue. http://jsfiddle.net/A3VXY/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.stop()` to stop flickr

**How to use:**

> $("*element*").stop().fadeTo();

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8msQ9/1/)